# call functions in different classes

Tags: function, class, swift3, xcode8

I want to show alert message at my TableView (class UITableViewController) when my app started. I created the function at another class UIViewController. 
This is my function:

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

   func showAlert(titleText: String, messageText: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message: messageText, preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    }
}
```

Then I call this function at another class:

```
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let new = AlertViewController()
        new.showAlert(titleText: "How is going?", messageText: "Have a nice day!")
```

but when I start my app, this alert message doesn't appear.
How can I solve this?? thank's a lot for help!!    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the alert, you are creating two controllers. First, the `AlertViewController` and then `UIAlertController`. You are attempting to show `UIAlertController` from an instance of `AlertViewController` but that controller is not shown!

To solve this, we will remove `AlertViewController` completely. Instead, we will use an extension and we will show the alert from a controller that is actually shown:

```
extension UIViewController {

   func showAlert(titleText: String, messageText: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: titleText, message: messageText, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in }

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Called as

```
self.showAlert(titleText: "How is going?", messageText: "Have a nice day!")
```